# How can my text input be empty if the value attribute is set?

Tags: html, reactjs, google-chrome-devtools

Have a look at the following screenshot. You can see that the text input field is empty, yet its `value` attribute is set to "b".

[image]

You'll also notice in the Properties tab, under `input`, that `value` here is set to "". Why are they different? What does this mean?

Could this be related to the fact that the input was rendered by React?

If it helps, here is the jsx responsible for this element (redacted):

```
return (
  <td
    key={field._id}
    className={`oldField ${colPos}`}
  >
    <input
      type="text"
      defaultValue={value}
      onChange={this.changeOldField(record, field)}
    />
  </td>
)
```

Comment: first-col works fine and it's not rendered by Reach?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Everything is rendered with React if that's what you mean. In the case of `first-col`, `last-col` and `oldField`, I added them via the `className` attribute of the `<td>` tags in my jsx (see my edit).

Comment: I just noticed that in the Properties tab, under 'input', `defaultValue` is set to 'b', as expected. Only `value` itself is not. Yet I didn't change the value of the field since the last React render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are changing the defaultValue based on something from the state. The defaultValue prop should be set only once and not changed later on, because any more changes will be ignored by React. If you want to change the value based on state you should use the normal value prop. Otherwise, if you want a predefined value to appear to the user and at the same time control the input when it gets changed, you can either use some logic in your code that handles both onChange and the code in your component that wants to automatically change the value, or possibly place it in the placeholder prop, which will give you something like what you want.

Comment: If I use `value` instead of `defaultValue`, then the user can't modify the field.  The `placeholder` prop is not as good since the user can't append to the placeholder value. As for "use some logic in your code that handles both onChange and the code in your component that wants to automatically change the value", I don't understand what you mean. I have an `onChange` listener on the input and I was relying on `defaultValue` to "automatically change the value" when the state changes.

Comment: btw the `onChange` handler doesn't change the state, something else does.

Comment: I solved it by forcing a change to the `key` of the `td` and now React is not ignoring the `defaultValue` prop. btw shouldn't this behaviour of React be considered a bug?